# Convert one list into another

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

My brain is blowing. I need to create a function that will take input and will convert it to another format.

From the array of objects, it should create an information object with an array of sorted by labels, and inside list value should have special order too. I need to find the way or algorithm to fix it.

This how input looks like:

```
[
  {
    "information": [
      {
        "label": "Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen",
        "list": [
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-24uxno": {
                "rows": [1]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-24uxno": {
                "rows": [2]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Allgemein",
        "list": [
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-24uxno": {
                "rows": [11]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-24uxno": {
                "rows": [12]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "information": [
      {
        "label": "Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen",
        "list": [
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-obbpw8": {
                "rows": [3]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-obbpw8": {
                "rows": [4]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "label": "Allgemein",
        "list": [
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-obbpw8": {
                "rows": [31]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "list": {
              "1953-obbpw8": {
                "rows": [32]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "information": [
    {
      "label": "Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen",
      "list": [
        {
          "list": {
            "1953-24uxno": {
              "rows": [1]
            },
            "1953-obbpw8": {
              "rows": [3]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "list": {
            "1953-24uxno": {
              "rows": [2]
            },
            "1953-obbpw8": {
              "rows": [4]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Allgemein",
      "list": [
        {
          "list": {
            "1953-24uxno": {
              "rows": [11]
            },
            "1953-obbpw8": {
              "rows": [31]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "list": {
            "1953-24uxno": {
              "rows": [12]
            },
            "1953-obbpw8": {
              "rows": [32]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: and what till now you tried to solve this? Can you share the code?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: So... group by `.information.label` and concatenate all the `.list.list`s?

Comment: Search for javascript reduce group

Comment: I tried in this away, https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-clarke-6gkec

Comment: @mplungjan I tried, but it did not help it making good structure but not exact result what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to keep track of the index `i` when iterating the list (next to `label`) in order to know to which index of the list to assign in the output

```js
const data = [{"information":[{"label":"Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen","list":[{"list":{"1953-24uxno":{"rows":[1]}}},{"list":{"1953-24uxno":{"rows":[2]}}}]},{"label":"Allgemein","list":[{"list":{"1953-24uxno":{"rows":[11]}}},{"list":{"1953-24uxno":{"rows":[12]}}}]}]},{"information":[{"label":"Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen","list":[{"list":{"1953-obbpw8":{"rows":[3]}}},{"list":{"1953-obbpw8":{"rows":[4]}}}]},{"label":"Allgemein","list":[{"list":{"1953-obbpw8":{"rows":[31]}}},{"list":{"1953-obbpw8":{"rows":[32]}}}]}]}]
const out = {}
data.forEach(({ information }) => {
  information.forEach(({ label, list }) => {
    out[label] = out[label] || { list: [] }
    const row = out[label]
    // [{list:{19...}}, {list:{19...}}]
    list.forEach(({ list }, i) => {
      const [k, v] = Object.entries(list)[0]
      row.list[i] = row.list[i] || { list: {} }
      row.list[i].list[k]  = v
    })
  })
})
console.log(JSON.stringify({ information: out }, null, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

For a start, but don't expecting that I will do all the job for you

```js
const truc1 = 
  [ { "information": 
      [ { "label": "Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen"
        , "list": 
          [ { "list": { "1953-24uxno": { "rows": [ 1 ] } } } 
          , { "list": { "1953-24uxno": { "rows": [ 2 ] } } } 
          ] 
        } 
      , { "label": "Allgemein"
        , "list": 
          [ { "list": { "1953-24uxno": { "rows": [ 11 ] } } } 
          , { "list": { "1953-24uxno": { "rows": [ 12 ] } } } 
    ] } ] } 
  , { "information": 
      [ { "label": "Wich­tigs­te Leis­tun­gen"
        , "list": 
          [ { "list": { "1953-obbpw8": { "rows": [ 3 ] } } } 
          , { "list": { "1953-obbpw8": { "rows": [ 4 ] } } } 
          ] 
        } 
      , { "label": "Allgemein"
        , "list": 
          [ { "list": { "1953-obbpw8": { "rows": [ 31 ] } } } 
          , { "list": { "1953-obbpw8": { "rows": [ 32 ] } } } 
  ] } ] } ]


const truc2 = truc1.reduce((a,e)=>
  {
  let k = Object.keys(e)[0]
  if (!a[k]) a[k] = []
  // continue with e[k]... ( is eq to "information": [...
  return a
  },{})


console.log( JSON.stringify(truc2,0,2) )
```